# Google sheets API Writing data issue, Adding extra fields

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am using google-sheet-api for my project and it totally works fine most of the time. But at times it behaves differently. Last time I encountered with a problem that some of cells filled by my data which I am not intend to. It randomly picked one of the values from my data and filled up other cells in my row. So my question is , Is this something with on my side or  google-sheets-api issues ??

Used code:

```
const writeReq = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({ 
  spreadsheetId:id, range:'range', valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED", 
  resource:{ 
    values:[ 
      ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6", "data7", "data8"], 
    ] 
  } 
})
```

Comment: Can you provide your relevant code - to see if there is something that fills the cells differently form what you expect?

Comment: ////const writeReq = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
            spreadsheetId:id,
            range:'range',
            valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED",
            resource:{
                values:[
                    ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6", "data7", "data8"],
                ]
            }
        }) /////



this is the code what I am using for appending the row, but I don't think it has something to  do with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's a bug

- Issues with [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) appending values at the wrong location in the sheet are already know and reported on Google's Issue Tracker - see [API values.append sometimes adds row not where it supposed to](https://issuetracker.google.com/185272184) and [Sheets V4 does not provide any suitable append operation](https://issuetracker.google.com/188096929)
- What you can do is "star" the issues to increase visibility, so that hopefully the issue will be fixed soon